# How to change configuration of eth0 without restarting other interface (CentOS, Redhat)

Tags: networking

I need to setup a static IP for eth0, my server has multiple network interfaces and I don't want to bring any of them, except for eth0 down.

I found lot of guides like https://www.howtoforge.com/linux-basics-set-a-static-ip-on-centos but all of them ends with "now restart networking" or "now reboot"

I can't reboot this server, nor I can bring down eth1 even if it was for a microsecond. How would I change eth0 config without touching other interfaces?

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

`ifdown eth0` to stop and `ifup eth0` to start

Comment: along with ifconfig eth0 192.168.2.3 up to specify IP. dont forget to edit configuration file.

Comment: This will not with SSH, runing ifdown will terminate SSH connection.